# How to solve the bootstrap form modal submit button pass the only first row data every time?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

Bootstrap edit form Model passes the only first row data on every other row. How do I fix this?

I have display list of records in the table view and each row there is two button 1.Done and 2.view.

suppose user clicking on the done button show the bootstrap form modal with particular row data and after showing form modal, user press the submit button of bootstrap modal form pass the first row data to the controller on every other row so how to fix that problem?

**View**

```
<a class="modalLink" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#con-close-modal<?php echo $getemi->loan_payments_id; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $getemi->loan_payments_id; ?>"> <span class="btn btn-success btn-rounded waves-effect waves-light">Done</span>
</a>
<!-- Start Model -->
<div id="con-close-modal<?php echo $getemi->loan_payments_id; ?>" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title mt-0">Pay Your Outstanding Amount</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!--  <form method="POST" id="frm_pay_installment"> -->
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Current EMI</label>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input type="text" name="current_emi" id="current_emi" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $current_emi; ?>" placeholder="Current EMI" disabled>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Pay Amount</label>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input type="text" id="payment_amount" name="payment_amount" class="form-control" placeholder="Pay Amount" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Payment Info:</label>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="payment_details" name="payment_details" placeholder="Details Of Cash / Cheque/ DD :"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" id="loan_payments_id" name="loan_payments_id" value="<?php echo $getemi->loan_payments_id; ?>">

                <div class="modal-footer" style="justify-content: center;">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                    <!-- <input type="submit" name="btn_pay" value="Pay" class="btn btn-info"> -->

                    <button class="pay_installment btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light" id="btn_pay">Pay</button>
                </div>
                <!--  </form> -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- / Emd modal -->
```

**Ajax Call**

```
<script>
    $('.pay_installment').click(function() {
        var payment_amount = $('#payment_amount').val();
        var payment_details = $('#payment_details').val();
        var loan_payments_id = $('#loan_payments_id').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url('admin/payInstallmentAmount');?>",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                payment_details: payment_details,
                payment_amount: payment_amount,
                loan_payments_id: loan_payments_id
            },

            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data['success'] == false) {

                    $('#show_error_message').html(data['error']);
                    return false;
                    console.log(data);
                }

                if (data['success'] == true) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#con-close-modal' + data['loan_payments_id']).modal('hide');
                    location.reload();
                    $('#success_message').html(data['message']);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
```

});

**Controller**

```
public function payInstallmentAmount() {
    $data = array();

    $this - > form_validation - > set_rules('payment_amount', 'Pay Amount', 'required');
    $this - > form_validation - > set_rules('payment_details', 'Payment Details', 'required');

    if ($this - > form_validation - > run() == false) {
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['error'] = validation_errors();
    } else {
        $post_data = $this - > input - > post();

        if ($this - > AdminModel - > payInstallmentAmount($post_data)) {
            $loan_payments_id = $post_data['loan_payments_id'];
            $data['success'] = true;
            $data['message'] = "Successfully Submit Installment Amount";
            $data['loan_payments_id'] = $loan_payments_id;
        }

    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: You are telling that there are multiple payment_amount, payment_details, loan_payments_id fields in page?

Comment: yes there are total three fields in bootstrap form modal @gnanz

Comment: No... He means to ask if the fields are repeated. As in, if there is more than one with the same name.

Comment: Is there a foreach generated the modals?

Comment: yes modals in  within foreach loop @Alex

Comment: Well then your issue is self explanatory and exactly what gnanzs answer addresses. You can't have multiple inputs with the same name and expect it to work, chrome Dev tools I believe even issues errors for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this model dialog code is within for loop then place it outside of for loop and populate the model when click **done** button

(or )

The element id's need to be unique within the page, since you populate model dialog for each row. there are 'n' number of **payment_amount, payment_details, loan_payments_id** fields in page. to get the clear idea what i'm talking about right click on page'view page source' and search for any field id (eg: payment_amount)

change that to class name then You need to pass the model dialog id to javascript method when Pay button is clicked, so that you can access the element using parent id like

```
<input type="hidden" class="loan_payments_id" name="loan_payments_id" value="<?php echo $getemi->loan_payments_id; ?>">
```

Script:

```
payment_amount= $('#con-close-modal'+payment_id+' .payment_amount').val()
```

**Id from play_button**
There are many methods available to get the id,
1. Provide as argument to function

```
<button class="pay_installment btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light" id="btn_pay" onclick="pay_installment(<?php echo $getemi->loan_payments_id; ?>)">Pay</button>


function pay_installment(payment_id) {
        var payment_amount = $('#con-close-modal'+payment_id+' .payment_amount').val();
        var payment_details = $('#con-close-modal'+payment_id+' .payment_details').val();
```

2. provide as part of button id

   button class="pay_installment btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light" **id="btn_pay_loan_payments_id; ?>"**>Pay button>

   ```
    $('.pay_installment').click(function() {
    buttonid=this.id;
   payment_id=buttonid.split('_')[2]
     var payment_amount = $('#con-close-modal'+payment_id+' .payment_amount').val();
               var payment_details = $('#con-close-modal'+payment_id+' .payment_details').val();
   -----------
   }
   ```

Comment: how to get the textbox  value in ajax call when pay button is pressed ?